# Find null children

Tags: c#

```
public class Node
{
    public Node rightNode;
    public Node bottomNode;
    public double x_position;
    public double z_position;
    public double width;
    public double length;
    public bool isOccupied;
}
```

In this code i have  a self-referencing property which is `rightNode`.
So my question is, how can I determine all nodes with `null` `rightNode`.

```
var rootNode = this.rootNode;
while (rootNode != null)
{
    rootNode = rootNode.right
}
```

So far I need to iterate all the branches to check if it's null, is there another way to return all null objects without iterating it?

Comment: `determine all nodes` in where? in a list of nodes? where is that list? how is that list defined? where do you want to store those "all nodes"?

Comment: What have you tried? The code you posted doesn't make any checks, it just assigns a variable

Comment: @Jcl that behaves like a linked list, `self-referencing class` meaning rightNode also contains an instance of `Node` and so on

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is working, but I need some implementation or "the efficient one" to return all nulls in one go

Comment: @Desperado I know what is a linked list... and I understand your class... but what do you have as a source of instances? a single node? how do you want to store the result? in a `IEnumerable<Node>`? in a single node with the `rightNode` references set?

Comment: I imagine you want to do some sort of recursive method. Something that takes in a node, checks the left and ride children for null. If the left node isn't null, pass the left node back into the function. If the right is, `yield return` it, else pass the right child back into the function.

Comment: For each node do you need to check the right node and the bottom node or just the right node (not the null check but do you need to check the bottom node's right node as well as the right node's right node)?

Comment: @plusheen yes that is correct, you got it right. I updated the question also

Comment: @Desperado a "way to return all null objects without iterating it"? How would you find something in a **linked** list without iterating through it?

Comment: @ardila look at codor's answer

Comment: @Desperado you see that `foreach` in his answer? Yea, that's iteration, even if it's wrapped up nicely in a property for you. You want to find the leaf nodes of a tree: either traverse the list and find them, or keep pointers to them.

Comment: @ardila no doubt on that, I accepted it due to reusability and elegance. I know that we need to traverse the "tree" in order to access it's child. An exception only would be if the item is the first item in the tree

Comment: @Desperado well, your `is there another way to return all null objects without iterating it?` sentence in your question actually points that you **do** have doubts on that

Comment: @ardila please provide your suggestion as an answer, might be a good solution than the accepted answer

Comment: @Jcl thanks for pointing it out, lets move on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possiblity would be to create a property which returns the entire tree in a suitable serialization, say [inorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), as follows.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> InOrder
{
    get
    {
        if (null != bottomNode)
            foreach (var bNode in bottomNode.InOrder)
                yield return bNode;
        yield return this;
        if (null != rightNode)
            foreach (var rNode in rightNode.InOrder)
                yield return rNode;
    }
}
```

Via this property, the tree can be accessed with Linq and the desired nodes can be obtaines as follows, where `root` is the root of the tree.

```
var DesiredNodes = root.InOrder.Where(iNode => null == iNode.rightNode);
```

For the more Linq-ish inclined, the property can be rewritten as follows.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> InOrder
{
    get
    {
        return (null == bottomNode ? new Node[]{} : bottomNode.InOrder)
        .Concat(new Node[]{this})
        .Concat(null == rightNode ? new Node[]{} : rightNode.InOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this code and it returns all the nodes regardless if it;s left or right, How to return the all right only?

Answer (score 4):

You can store all nodes which have a null rightNode in a set. The set would be static (i.e. there is just one for all nodes). `rightNode` would have to become a property: when it is set to null, the node enters itself into thr HashSet; if it is non-null, it removes itself from it.

Example:

```
public class Node
{
    // Added to store null nodes
    public static HashSet<Node> _nullNodes = new HashSet<Node>();

    Node _rightNode;

    // Changed to property in order to perform 
    // insertion/deletion from set of null nodes
    public Node rightNode
    {
        get { return _rightNode; }
        set
        {   // we don't care about redundant add/remove.
            if (value == null) { _nullNodes.Add(this); }
            else               { _nullNodes.Remove(this); }
            _rightNode = value;
        }
    }
    public Node bottomNode;
    public double x_position;
    public double z_position;
    public double width;
    public double length;
    public bool isOccupied;

    // Added for identification
    public object tag;


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return tag == null ? "Un-tagged" : tag.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.tag = "node 1";
        n.rightNode = new Node();
        n.rightNode.tag = "node 2, null right";
        n.rightNode.rightNode = null;

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Null nodes: ");

        // should print one node
        foreach (var node in Node._nullNodes)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("  " + node);
        }

        n.rightNode.rightNode = new Node();

        // should print no node any more (we replaced null with a node).
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Null nodes: ");
        foreach (var node in Node._nullNodes)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("  " + node);
        }

    }
```

Sample session:

```
Null nodes:
  node 2, null right
Null nodes:
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is easy, provided that the node tree has no cycles.

```
public List<Node> AllWrong(Node root)
{
    List<Node> wrongs = new List<Node>();

    if (root == null)
        return wrongs;

    if (root.RightNode == null)
    {
        // This is not right
        wrongs.Add(root);
    }

    // Recursively search - assumes this is a tree 
    wrongs.AddRange(AllWrong(root.rightNode));
    wrongs.AddRange(AllWrong(root.bottomNode));

    return wrongs;
}
```